# Как работает наследование значений конструкторов?

Tags: c++

```
Kind_of_Animals Turtles ("Черепаха", 'W', 1500, 3);
Animal Masha ("Маша");
```

Kind_of_Animal - объект класса, хранящий данные о видах животных. Animal - объект дочернего класса, который перенимает, логично, все от базового плюс имя. Я знаю, что вот так:  `Animal(string name) : Kind_of_Animals("Черепаха", 'W', 1500, 3)` можно сделать наследование, но мне нужно, чтоб именно при инициализации Masha можно было указать, что она наследует данные от Turtles, при условии, что объектов класса Kind_of_Animals может быть несколько. Возможно ли такое вытворить?

Comment: Конструктор, которому передается ссылка на объект родителя?

Comment: @Harry, если так это можно реализовать, то да

Comment: Ну а почему бы нет?...

Comment: @Harry только вот я не совсем знаю, как это правильно реализовать

Comment: `Animal::Animal(const char * name, const Kind_of_Animals& who)` Если это потомок, и есть копирующий конструктор, то продолжение — `:Kind_of_Animals(who)`. Более конкретно без описания классов не ответить.

Comment: @Harry спасибо.